# How do I input data in a function as it is not working?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
def employee(ID, first_name, last_name, weekly_hours, hourly_pay_rate, income_tax_rate):
    ID = input("Employee ID: ")
    first_name= input("Employee's Last Name: ")
    last_name = input("Employee's First Name: ")
    weekly_hours = float(input("Weekly Hours: "))
    hourly_pay_rate = float(input("Hourly Pay Rate: "))
    income_tax_rate = float(input("Income Tax Rate: "))
```

How do I make this get user data like for example my name is get roasted.
I want the user to be able to type getroasted
but in the console there is nothing.

Comment: what is the error you are facing in this code ?

Comment: You have defined a function. Now you need to call it.

Comment: "it is not working" is not a problem statement. Please provide more details and a [mre].

Answer (score 2):

First, since you're creating the variables inside the `employee` function, you don't need to pass any parameters to it:

```py
def employee():
    ID = input("Employee ID: ")
    first_name= input("Employee's Last Name: ")
    last_name = input("Employee's First Name: ")
    weekly_hours = float(input("Weekly Hours: "))
    hourly_pay_rate = float(input("Hourly Pay Rate: "))
    income_tax_rate = float(input("Income Tax Rate: "))
```

Then, you need to call the function to be able to execute it:

```
employee()
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to pass the arguments to the function if you are taking the input from inside the function. Just omit the argument from the function definition and you are good to go.

```py
def employee():
    ID = input("Employee ID: ")
    first_name= input("Employee's Last Name: ")
    last_name = input("Employee's First Name: ")
    weekly_hours = float(input("Weekly Hours: "))
    hourly_pay_rate = float(input("Hourly Pay Rate: "))
    income_tax_rate = float(input("Income Tax Rate: "))
```